# Unity3d: How to build from command line specifing Scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Good day.

I'd like to make different Build for my Unity WebGl application.

In particular I'd like to know if there is some sort of command line to start a build :

- Specifing Scene name to build
- Specifing Destination path

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a build script inside your project. Take a look at [BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildPlayerPipeline.html).

And then you have to call your script's build method from the command line. Take a look at [this document](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html) to learn how to call Unity in silence mode and pass arguments (that is, you can either define the scenes to build and destination path in your build script or you can pass them as arguments).